# How do the python logical operators and, or work without if?

Tags: python, python-3.x

After finding these two lines online, I don't understand how the first line works to have the same effect as the second line

```
current = letter >= prev_letter and current + letter or letter

current = current + letter if letter >= prev_letter else letter
```

Comment: Can you also mention what data is stored in those variables? It will be relevant too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of an `and` expression is either the first falsy operand or the second operand. The result of an `or` expression is either the first truthy operand or the second operand. It's also worth nothing that the first statement is equivalent to:

```
current = (letter >= prev_letter and current + letter) or letter
```

This means that `letter >= prev_letter and current + letter` will either evaluate to `False` if the condition is `False`, or `current + letter`. This result is then the left-hand side of the `or` expression. If `False`, the `or` expression will then evaluate to `letter`. Otherwise, it will stay as `current + letter`.

However, these two expressions may not be equivalent depending on the values of the variables. For example, suppose `current` is -1, `letter` is 1, and `prev_letter` is 0. Then the `and` expression evaluates to 0. This means the result of the `or` expression will be `letter`, which is 1. For these same values, the second expression would set `current` to 0.